# Spare parts database for older cars

Tags: parts

A 1998 Camry Cashmere Beige Metallic needs a driver-side exterior door handle.  Attempts to find the part in the color has been challenging.  I was able to find the part in black locally (they are intended to be painted), but I would prefer to buy a used part that is painted.

Is there another database besides eBay I can search for parts?  Hopefully one pops up on eBay because sellers are more competitive.  Thank you for the good suggestions.

## List of suggested databases from responses:

- [http://salvageyard.net](http://salvageyard.net/)

Comment: Black replacement parts are intended to be painted to match the car. Try a Google search for "used car parts". There are a bunch of sites which you can search for parts by make, model, year and location to find used parts in your area and or have them shipped to you.

Comment: This is very much a shopping question and difficult to answer not knowing your locality but in the UK there are services which let you register a parts request which is sent to a group of scrap yards and they email you back within a couple of days.  There may be something similar where you are.  Here is one link to such a UK based service http://www.breakeryard.com/partfinder

Comment: Greetings from the other side of the pond: thank you for the constructive response.  I neglected  mentioned that I am Florida.  My intent was to understand what are the preferred suppliers (and why) of my peers

Answer (score 2):

For start 98 is not that old so there will be many of these in yards scattered through out the country.
Next new parts are in black to allow painting to match the cars current color.  Pre painted parts will be found but variations in color will exist simply for the reason one car does not age the same as another.  So buying a painted part may show some differences in color if your willing to accept that.

As for how to find the USED part in the right color can be best approached in one of two ways.
First is through your local junk/salvage yards parts network, they will if asked find the part (at least locally if available).
Or you can do this with by searching the favorite search engine for "junkyard network"  and you will find several used parts networks operated by the various junkyard and parts houses associations.
For instance a simple search yields [Salvageyard.net](http://salvageyard.net)  which I see has several handles offered at this time.